# Read unicode encoded JSON and access it using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, unicode

I have a very huge unicode JSON data of the following format

> {u'completed': True, u'entries': [{u'absolute_time':
>   u'2017-05-17T10:41:52Z',    u'command': None,    u'level':
>   u'NORMAL',......

It has Json objects within JSON objects. Unable to read it and parse it due to the encoding. Tried the following code.
Could someone please tell how to parse it and convert it to a normal JSON object.

```
with open(r"inp.json", 'r') as jsonData:
    jsonToPython = json.load(jsonData) #gives error here itself
    #jsonData = ast.literal_eval(jsonData)
    print(json.dumps(jsonToPython))
    #print (jsonToPython)
```

Comment: If that file *really* contains `{u'completed': True, u'entries' ...` then it's not JSON.

Comment: And why is that so?

Comment: Because it violates the syntax rules for JSON? http://json.org/

Comment: No this is for unicode encoding actually.The u represents unicode

Comment: It represents Unicode strings in *Python source code*, which is something completely different than JSON. It is invalid in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the (stringified) python object using [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#module-ast):

```
>>> #obj = open(r"inp.json", 'r').read()
>>> obj = "{u'completed': True, u'entries': [{u'absolute_time': u'2017-05-17T10:41:52Z'}]}"
>>> ast.literal_eval(obj)
{'completed': True, 'entries': [{'absolute_time': '2017-05-17T10:41:52Z'}]}
>>>
```

Comment: The only problem is each JSON object is very huge and spanning about 25 lines each. so putting it like this in a single line will be impossible.